# Keep label updating through segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I have a small sample project i'm using to figure out how to implement this on my main project. This simple project has 2 VC's both with segues to each other.

On the initial VC is a button which leads to the TimerVC (both using the same class).

The TimerVC has a button and a label. When the button is pressed the label will increase by 1 every second.

If the timer is on and I segue back to the initial VC and then to the TimerVC the timer continues but the label stops updating.

How can I keep the label updating? The timer keeps going in the back-end but once the segue happens the label stops updating.

EDIT: Code provided below. The Timer is also more complex to represent a little of what I'm trying to do.

VC.H

```
NSTimer * timer;

NSTimer * updateTimer;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *idleOutler;

- (IBAction)idleAttack:(id)sender;
```

VC.M

```
int enemy001Hp = 100;

int deadEnemy = NO;
int noHealth = 0;

bool enemy001Active = NO;

- (void) enemy1 {
enemy001Active = YES;
self.enemyHpLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", enemy001Hp];
}


- (void) enemyDamageTimer {
if (enemy001Active == YES) {
    enemy001Hp -= 50;
    self.enemyHpLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",enemy001Hp];
  }
}

- (void) updateLabelTimer {
if (enemy001Active == YES) {
    self.enemyHpLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", enemy001Hp];
} 
}

- (void) stopTimer {
[timer invalidate];
timer = nil;
self.enemyHpLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self enemy1];
if (enemy001Active) {
    self.enemyHpLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", enemy001Hp];
} else if (enemy002Active == YES) {
    self.enemyHpLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", enemy002Hp];

}
}

- (IBAction)idleAttack:(id)sender {
idleOn = YES;
self.idleOutler.hidden = YES;
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(enemyDamageTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
 updateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(updateLabelTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
if (enemy001Active == YES) {
    if (enemy001Hp <= 0) {
        [self enemy2];
        enemy001Active = NO;
        enemy002Active = YES;
    }
} else if (enemy002Active == YES) {
    if (enemy002Hp <= 0) {
        self.enemyHpLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"];
        enemy002Hp = 0;
        enemy002Active = NO;
        [self stopTimer];
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It will be easier to help if you provide relevant code.

Comment: Can you please delete all irrelevant code?